# jenkins job dsl - No signature of method: java.lang.String.call()

Tags: jenkins, groovy, dsl, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am unable to run this piece of code:

```
buildPath = 'applications'
buildJob(['java', 'nodejs'])


def buildJob(def jobList){
  for(job in jobList){
    def jobName = "${job}_seed"
    def jobDescription = "Jenkins DSL seed for ${job}"
    def jobScriptPath = "resources/dsl/${jobName}.groovy"
    job("${buildPath}/${jobName}")
  }
}
```

So, I am getting this error:

```sh
Processing provided DSL script
ERROR: (script, line 12) No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [applications/java_seed]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), take(int), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I do not see where or what is causing this error. I created a single job outside of the `buildJob(def jobList)` function and it is working but I need to do the loop to automation the jobs creation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are iterating string array in the following line:

```
for(job in jobList){
```

and using variable `job` for this.

then you try to invoke method `call` on this variable:

```
job("${buildPath}/${jobName}")
```

Answer (score 9):

Posting a similar issue i have run into. Isn't much around the web on this issue.

`No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [some-value]`

Say we are implementing a job dsl plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/multibranch-build-strategy-extension-plugin) like:

```
includeRegionBranchBuildStrategy {

    includedRegions(String value)

}
```

And we have code like:

```
def includedRegions = r ? String.join("\n", r) : null

branchSources {
  branchSource {
    buildStrategies {
      if(includedRegions){
        includeRegionBranchBuildStrategy {
          includedRegions(includedRegions)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Need to rename your variable to get it to work! e.g the method can't have the same name as a var defined above.

```
def regions = r ? String.join("\n", r) : null

branchSources {
  branchSource {
    buildStrategies {
      if(regions){
        includeRegionBranchBuildStrategy {
          includedRegions(regions)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```